# Symfony/Doctrine - Inheritance ManyToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In advance, thank you for your help.

I have different type of user, and in my example an User can have multiple Brand and a Brand multiple User. 
   User -> ManyToMany -> Brand
I need advice to do that but i don't know what is the best way using inheritance.

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\User\UserRepository")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"admin" = "UserAdmin", "brand" = "UserBrand", "developper" = "UserDev"})
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"usernameCanonical"}, errorPath="username", message="user.username.already_used", groups={"Registration", "Profile"}, repositoryMethod="findByUniqueCriteria")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"emailCanonical"}, errorPath="email", message="user.email.already_used", groups={"Registration", "Profile"}, repositoryMethod="findByUniqueCriteria")
*/
abstract class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    const TYPE = 'Parent';
    const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_USER';
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_brand")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\User\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
class UserBrand extends User
{
    const TYPE = 'Brand';
    const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_BRAND';  
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_admin")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\User\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
class UserAdmin extends User
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a many-to-many bidirectional relationship from User to Brand. You should update both entities and their orm files to have relationships with each other.
Look at the following example from symfony document.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional